# Mouseover Shaking on List Items

Tags: css, positioning, margin, padding

How can I prevent shaking when I mouse over list items on **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/32pFM/1/)**?  I have tried different margins and paddings up until now. I have also checked which css element overflows but I couldn't find any result.

my css is here:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
    background:#000000;
    color:#fff;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}


.temizle{clear:both;}

#containerANA{
    width:1100px;
    height:auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font:10px arial, helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;

}


#content{
    width:100%;
    margin-top:0px;
}


#content p{
  position: relative;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  top:0px;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;    
  color: #769B4E;
  font-size:18px;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
  text-align:justify;   
  border: 0px solid #769B4E;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#content p a{
    color:#ccc;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#content p a:hover{
    background:#e5da5f;
    color:#000;
}



.ikinciSol{
    width:550px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    margin-right:0px;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-align:left;
}

.ikinciSol h1{
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color:#fb891a;
}

.ikinciSol ul
{
    list-style-type: none;

}

.ikinciSol #playlist li {
    margin-left:50px;
}

.ikinciSol ul li .singer{
    font-size:18px;
    display:inline;
}

.ikinciSol ul li .song{
    font-size:14px;
    display:inline;
}

.ikinciSol ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    margin-right:5px;

}

.ikinciSol ul li .singer a:hover{
    background:#e5da5f;
    color:#000;
}

.ikinciSol ul li  .song a:hover{
    background:#FF9966;
    color:#000;
}

.artist_track{
    margin-right:12px;

}
.fav{

}    



.ilgiliOge{
    width:402px;
    height:306px;
    font-size:24px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you hover your mouse, the height of the `<li>`changes due to the share buttons. To prevent this from happening, you should give a `min-height`to the list-item. On top of that, if you want to keep the text centered in relation to your buttons, you should also give it a `line-height` and some more tweaking.

CSS Code:

```
.ikinciSol #playlist li {
    min-height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
}
.ikinciSol #playlist li .fav a {
    position:relative;
    top:5px;
}
```

JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/vZnFF/

PS: You shouldn't add breaks between list items.
PS2: You could do the same :hover efect with just CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have the social media icons be equal to or less than the size of the `<li>`.

http://jsfiddle.net/32pFM/3/

```
.fav img{
    height: 16px;
}
```

Note: this is only one option, you could also set the height of the list elements. The reason you're getting that jumping is due to hiding/showing objects that are larger than the height of the containing element.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right path by playing with the margins, but they weren't having any effect because you have the .singer class set to "inline". Change it to "inline-block" and then play with the margin-top, and you can achieve what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the height of the Facebook and twitter icons. You may want to make smaller images or set a height to the image:

```
.fav img{
    height: 1em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nivas/tuUhX/1/